# GNU make : copy certain files from many location to a certain directory

Tags: gnu-make

I am trying to copy headers files from many locations to a certain directory.
But the problem is with the same file name ie., if there are two files with same name present in different locations. Make just copies any one of the files. Is there any way to detect this duplication.

Thanks

Comment: Your build will almost certainly not work as intended if you copy,
say, both `a/b/foo.h` and `c/foo.h` to `d/foo.h`. Nor if you copy
just one of them. Leave the headers where they are: use [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) and pass the right `-I` arguments to your compiles. [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed for an answer.

Comment: I want to detect it before compilation. So that I can throw an error before compilation starts.

Comment: And why is it an error? You need to explain and illustrate *the problem*.
Do this in the body of your question. not in comments.